# Count individuals appearing at bracketed frequencies across cumulative intervals of discrete time

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset of events occurring at spatial coordinates over time (years). I wish to get a sense of the *ergodicity* of locations over time, that is the extent to which events repeat at the same locations. (The volume of events per location is indifferent.)

In order to do so, I have opted to count the years in which locations are active within intervals of several years, from 1 to the interval length. (Locations may activate in discontinuous years). Then I look at how the count of such locations increases as intervals accumulate up to the entire period. I provide a toy example below, but my actual dataset is much larger, with larger intervals.

I wish to know whether the logic and programming are sound and whether they can be simplified/improved.

```
#Toy dataset of 100 events at 60 point locations over 10 years from 1990 to 1999.
df1 <- structure(list(year = c("1997", "1996", "1998", "1995", "1997", "1995", "1995", "1997", "1997", "1999", "1997", "1999", "1996", "1997", "1997", "1991", "1996", "1992", "1993", "1999", "1997", "1995", "1997", "1996", "1997", "1997", "1991", "1997", "1997", "1998", "1999", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1996", "1998", "1997", "1999", "1999", "1995", "1998", "1996", "1996", "1997", "1995", "1996", "1995", "1995", "1994", "1997", "1998", "1999", "1999", "1999", "1995", "1999", "1999", "1999", "1999", "1997", "1999", "1994", "1994", "1996", "1994", "1999", "1999", "1993", "1997", "1999", "1999", "1998", "1999", "1998", "1999", "1997", "1999", "1996", "1996", "1996", "1999", "1996", "1995", "1995", "1997", "1996", "1999", "1999", "1997", "1994", "1995", "1995", "1999", "1996", "1998", "1997", "1997", "1995", "1999", "1998"), lng = c(127.107, 126.855, 126.896, 126.908, 126.951, 126.994, 126.833, 126.855, 126.939, 126.65, 127.01, 127.107, 126.864, 127.107, 126.65, 126.864, 126.951, 127.01, 127.139, 127.107, 127.492, 127.113, 127.119, 126.831, 127.009, 127.139, 127.047, 127.124, 126.732, 127.047, 126.908, 127.197, 126.903, 127.077, 126.951, 127.096, 126.972, 126.831, 127.047, 127.035, 126.85, 126.722, 126.932, 127.124, 126.872, 127.035, 127.069, 126.678, 127.124, 126.65, 126.887, 127.139, 127.047, 127.04, 126.855, 127.047, 127.01, 127.01, 126.841, 127.018, 126.937, 126.952, 127.047, 126.738, 126.831, 126.935, 126.871, 126.911, 126.707, 127.107, 126.972, 127.01, 126.937, 127.5, 126.968, 127.113, 127.035, 126.865, 126.831, 127.054, 127.035, 127.199, 126.722, 127.518, 126.98, 127.12, 126.972, 126.874, 126.965, 127.009, 127.518, 126.873, 126.722, 126.848, 127.009, 127, 127.113, 126.937, 127.107, 126.951), lat = c(37.5145, 37.5165, 37.5264, 37.5638, 37.3164, 37.4264, 37.5243, 37.5165, 37.5124, 37.4637, 37.3038, 37.5145, 37.4785, 37.5145, 37.4637, 37.4785, 37.3926, 37.3038, 37.434, 37.5145, 37.2298, 36.9921, 37.3827, 37.1995, 37.2911, 37.4449, 37.5172, 37.5301, 37.447, 37.5172, 37.5638, 37.5384, 37.5683, 37.1498, 37.3926, 37.5256, 37.2572, 37.3219, 37.6688, 37.2861, 37.551, 37.507, 37.3865, 37.5301, 37.4793, 37.2861, 37.205, 37.4094, 37.5301, 37.4637, 37.4954, 37.434, 37.5172, 37.5744, 37.5165, 37.5172, 37.3038, 37.3038, 37.2876, 37.5891, 37.5791, 37.4784, 37.5172, 37.5369, 37.3219, 37.3617, 37.3117, 37.388, 37.35, 37.5145, 37.2572, 37.3038, 37.5791, 37.2642, 37.3447, 36.9921, 37.2861, 37.2913, 37.3219, 37.5819, 37.2861, 37.6977, 37.507, 37.4138, 37.2965, 37.3004, 37.2572, 37.3618, 37.5384, 37.2911, 37.4138, 37.4612, 37.507, 37.534, 37.2911, 37.45, 36.9921, 37.5791, 37.5145, 37.3926)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) #for the unite function

#Cross-tabulate years and unique locations
df2 <- df1 %>% distinct(year,lng,lat) %>% unite(coord, c("lng", "lat"), sep=";")
df2 <- table(df2$coord, df2$year) %>% t %>% as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors=F)
colnames(df2) <- c("year", "coord", "freq")

#Quantify ergodicity: Bin by 2-year interval & count active years in current and previous 
#intervals. Start with frequencies of 1 or 2.
df2 %>% filter(year<1992 & freq!=0) %>% group_by(coord) %>% mutate(freq=sum(freq)) %>% 
  filter(freq<3) %>% distinct(coord) %>% nrow
#[1] 2 (2 distinct locations are active for 1 or 2 years in 1990-1991)
df2 %>% filter(year<1994 & freq!=0) %>% group_by(coord) %>% mutate(freq=sum(freq)) %>% 
  filter(freq<3) %>% distinct(coord) %>% nrow
#[1] 5 (5 distinct locations are active for 1 or 2 years in 1990-1993)
df2 %>% filter(year<1996 & freq!=0) %>% group_by(coord) %>% mutate(freq=sum(freq)) %>% 
  filter(freq3) %>% distinct(coord) %>% nrow
#[1] 22
df2 %>% filter(year<1998 & freq!=0) %>% group_by(coord) %>% mutate(freq=sum(freq)) %>% 
  filter(freq<3) %>% distinct(coord) %>% nrow
#[1] 46
df2 %>% filter(year<2000 & freq!=0) %>% group_by(coord) %>% mutate(freq=sum(freq)) %>% 
  filter(freq<3) %>% distinct(coord) %>% nrow
#[1] 53
```

After 1-2, I move on to frequency brackets of 3-4, etc. until the 10-year period of analysis is covered. Predictably, frequencies of 3-4 would not be found in the first interval of 2 years, etc. The desired outcome is a table with frequency brackets as rows and cumulative intervals as columns, filled in with location counts.

EDIT: I have implemented nested loops for frequency brackets and cumulative intervals:

```
#Quantify ergodicity: Bin by 2-year interval & count active years in current and previous 
#intervals
df3 <- matrix(ncol=5, nrow=5) #build output matrix
colnames(df3) <- paste0(1990, "-", 1990+2*1:5-1) #cumulative intervals
rownames(df3) <- paste0(2*(1:5-1)+1, "-", 2*1:5) #frequency brackets
for (i in 1:5) {
  for (j in 1:5) {
  df3[i,j] <- df2 %>% filter(year<=1990+2*j-1 & freq!=0) %>% group_by(coord) %>% 
    mutate(freq=sum(freq)) %>% filter(freq>=2*(i-1)+1 & freq<=2*i) %>% distinct(coord) %>% 
    nrow
  }
}

df3
#            90-91 90-93 90-95 90-97 90-99
#1-2 years       2     5    22    46    53
#3-4 years       0     0     0     1     7
#5-6 years       0     0     0     0     0
#7-8 years       0     0     0     0     0
#9-10 years      0     0     0     0     0
```

(With more data, the diagonal and upper triangle tend to fill up, while the lower triangle comprises 0s by construction.)

Answer (score 1):

I think this achieves your desired output. Uses functions from the `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and `purrr` packages.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library("dplyr"))
library("tidyr")
library("purrr")

# input data
df1 <- structure(list(year = c("1997", "1996", "1998", "1995", "1997", "1995", "1995", "1997", "1997", "1999", "1997", "1999", "1996", "1997", "1997", "1991", "1996", "1992", "1993", "1999", "1997", "1995", "1997", "1996", "1997", "1997", "1991", "1997", "1997", "1998", "1999", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1996", "1998", "1997", "1999", "1999", "1995", "1998", "1996", "1996", "1997", "1995", "1996", "1995", "1995", "1994", "1997", "1998", "1999", "1999", "1999", "1995", "1999", "1999", "1999", "1999", "1997", "1999", "1994", "1994", "1996", "1994", "1999", "1999", "1993", "1997", "1999", "1999", "1998", "1999", "1998", "1999", "1997", "1999", "1996", "1996", "1996", "1999", "1996", "1995", "1995", "1997", "1996", "1999", "1999", "1997", "1994", "1995", "1995", "1999", "1996", "1998", "1997", "1997", "1995", "1999", "1998"), lng = c(127.107, 126.855, 126.896, 126.908, 126.951, 126.994, 126.833, 126.855, 126.939, 126.65, 127.01, 127.107, 126.864, 127.107, 126.65, 126.864, 126.951, 127.01, 127.139, 127.107, 127.492, 127.113, 127.119, 126.831, 127.009, 127.139, 127.047, 127.124, 126.732, 127.047, 126.908, 127.197, 126.903, 127.077, 126.951, 127.096, 126.972, 126.831, 127.047, 127.035, 126.85, 126.722, 126.932, 127.124, 126.872, 127.035, 127.069, 126.678, 127.124, 126.65, 126.887, 127.139, 127.047, 127.04, 126.855, 127.047, 127.01, 127.01, 126.841, 127.018, 126.937, 126.952, 127.047, 126.738, 126.831, 126.935, 126.871, 126.911, 126.707, 127.107, 126.972, 127.01, 126.937, 127.5, 126.968, 127.113, 127.035, 126.865, 126.831, 127.054, 127.035, 127.199, 126.722, 127.518, 126.98, 127.12, 126.972, 126.874, 126.965, 127.009, 127.518, 126.873, 126.722, 126.848, 127.009, 127, 127.113, 126.937, 127.107, 126.951), lat = c(37.5145, 37.5165, 37.5264, 37.5638, 37.3164, 37.4264, 37.5243, 37.5165, 37.5124, 37.4637, 37.3038, 37.5145, 37.4785, 37.5145, 37.4637, 37.4785, 37.3926, 37.3038, 37.434, 37.5145, 37.2298, 36.9921, 37.3827, 37.1995, 37.2911, 37.4449, 37.5172, 37.5301, 37.447, 37.5172, 37.5638, 37.5384, 37.5683, 37.1498, 37.3926, 37.5256, 37.2572, 37.3219, 37.6688, 37.2861, 37.551, 37.507, 37.3865, 37.5301, 37.4793, 37.2861, 37.205, 37.4094, 37.5301, 37.4637, 37.4954, 37.434, 37.5172, 37.5744, 37.5165, 37.5172, 37.3038, 37.3038, 37.2876, 37.5891, 37.5791, 37.4784, 37.5172, 37.5369, 37.3219, 37.3617, 37.3117, 37.388, 37.35, 37.5145, 37.2572, 37.3038, 37.5791, 37.2642, 37.3447, 36.9921, 37.2861, 37.2913, 37.3219, 37.5819, 37.2861, 37.6977, 37.507, 37.4138, 37.2965, 37.3004, 37.2572, 37.3618, 37.5384, 37.2911, 37.4138, 37.4612, 37.507, 37.534, 37.2911, 37.45, 36.9921, 37.5791, 37.5145, 37.3926)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

# cross-tabulate years and unique locations
df2 <- df1 %>%
  distinct(year, lng, lat) %>%
  unite(coord, c("lng", "lat"), sep=";") %>%
  count(year, coord, name = "freq") %>%
  complete(year, coord, fill = list(freq = 0L))

# quantify ergodicity: Bin by 2-year interval & count active years in current and previous intervals
output <- c(1990+2*1:5-1) %>% # the upper limits of the year ranges
  purrr::set_names(~paste0("1990-", .x)) %>%
  map_dfr( # filter df2 using this year range then combine into one data frame
    .f = ~ {
      df2 %>%
        filter(year <= .x & freq > 0)
    },
    .id = "year_range"
  ) %>%
  group_by(year_range, coord) %>%
  summarise(total_freq = sum(freq), .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(freq_range = cut( # cut the frequences into bins ("1 to 2", "3 to 4", etc). note that the data type of this column will be factors. can change this later, if desired
    total_freq,
    breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = 2))
  ) %>%
  count(year_range, freq_range)

# can reshape this as desired
output
#> # A tibble: 7 × 3
#>   year_range freq_range     n
#>   <chr>      <fct>      <int>
#> 1 1990-1991  (0,2]          2
#> 2 1990-1993  (0,2]          5
#> 3 1990-1995  (0,2]         22
#> 4 1990-1997  (0,2]         46
#> 5 1990-1997  (2,4]          1
#> 6 1990-1999  (0,2]         53
#> 7 1990-1999  (2,4]          7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>